# Why do people use this expression?

Tags: expressions

Lets say someone states "Tom runs fast, *how* fast is another question."

Why do and can people say 'is another question' even if there is no previous question explicitly stated?

Comment: The reference is to the ***implied, but not actually asked*** question ***Does Tom run fast**?* Similar to *Tom speaks French fluently, but his German is **a whole 'nother ball-game***, except with *that* example you'd struggle to explicitly identify the "implicit ball-game" being contrasted with ***another** one*).

Comment: I suspected that that is the case but what is the point of saying it then?